# WPF ADO.NET no results returned

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

I have a problem with returning results to DataGrid in WPF application using ADO.NET Framework.

First record is text, second too, third is date(if anyone could give me an answer how to make this string would be great).

First, DataGrid XAML code

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testViewSource1}}" Margin="113,290,0,0" Name="testDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" Loaded="testDataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="numerZamowieniaColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=numerZamowienia}" Header="numer Zamowienia" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iloscDostawcowColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=iloscDostawcow}" Header="ilosc Dostawcow" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dataUtworzeniaColumn" Header="data Utworzenia" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=dataUtworzenia, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I made event handler when this DataGrid is loaded :

```
zamowienieEntities zam = new zamowienieEntities();

 private void testDataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IBindingList users = ((from d in zam.Test
                               select new { d.numerZamowienia, d.iloscDostawcow, d.dataUtworzenia }
      ) as IListSource).GetList() as IBindingList;

        this.testDataGrid.DataContext = users;


    }
```

This is one of many approaches trying to make this work, and I'm sityting at it for couple hours now, and can't really find any specific answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably mean first *field* is text and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testViewSource1}}"
```

you bind `ItemsSource` to some `testViewSource1` resource so changing `DataContext`, as you do in this line

```
this.testDataGrid.DataContext = users;
```

won't affect source of `DataGrid` items. One solution to your problem is to set `ItemsSource` directly instead of `DataContext`

```
this.testDataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
```

and then you don't need `ItemsSource` binding, or if you want to set `DataContext` then you need to change `ItemsSource` binding to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

which will bind `ItemSource` to current `DataContext`

Comment: Still nothing, one way nor another. It connects to simple MSSQL query, but can't find a way to connect it with Linq (http://oi62.tinypic.com/aadwe8.jpg)

Comment: And `users`, when you debut it, has some data?

Comment: I assumed line 'IBindingList users = ((from d in zam.Test
                               select new { d.numerZamowienia, d.iloscDostawcow, d.dataUtworzenia }
      ) as IListSource).GetList() as IBindingList;' assigns select query to users

Comment: But did you debug it and confirmed that `users` has some items when you set `ItemSource`?

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, apparently event dataGrid_Loaded doesn't trigger, and it all worked after your instructions, method just didn't start. Thanks a lot for your time.